# nepali-english language translator api

Tags: api, localization, language-translation

I am looking for a language translator API for my project. I don't want to use the Google Translate API.

Can anyone suggest another? An open source translator would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Bing (Microsoft) machine translation engine.But it is almost the same as translate.google.com Or, you can make your own english-nepali machine tanslation system (engines), e.g.use this:
http://www.statmt.org/moses/
But, it will costs yo a lot of effort and time (question is whether it is worth of it).
Here is some discussion what options do you have if looking for some language translator for not-so-common language:
http://www.linkedin.com/groupItem?view=&gid=4370115&type=member&item=201871372&qid=3588ce96-f0c1-4789-a72d-b00a124127ee&trk=group_most_popular-0-b-ttl&goback=.gmp_4370115

(hopefully you will be able to display it)